# How to secure RESTful interface in JBoss AS 7

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.0, restful-authentication, ejb-3.1, jboss7.x

After successfully migrating my RESTful application to JBoss AS7, I would like to re-enable authentication (I used BASIC auth over SSL). It seems that this is now possible without writing XML configuration, just by using annotations.

Unfortunately, I cannot find which maven dependency I need to use to import the @WebService and @SecurityContext annotations.

Or is this completely going the wrong way? Is there a working example somewhere?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: For now, i have resurrected the old web.xml file defining authentication, roles etc. Basic authentication over SSL is running now. I am still searching for the annotated solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@javax.jws.WebService is part of JDK

you might also need:

```
org.jboss.ws.api.annotation.WebContext;
```

that has option to configure authMethod @WebContext(authMethod=AuthMethod.BASIC) and is part of

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbossws-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```